# How do I have a toString method properly print out the result of 2 mixed fractions?

Tags: java, string, swing

I am currently making a simple fractions calculator using java swing but I am now stuck on showing the results once I've added an option for having a mixed number. 
Right now, the executed program looks like this:

[image: Program when running]

Here is what I've attempted on the toString method:

```
public String toString() {
    if (this.numerator >= this.denominator) {
        String returnString = String.valueOf((this.numerator / this.denominator)+this.wholeNumber);
        int modulo = ((this.numerator % this.denominator)+wholeNumber);
        if (modulo > 0) {
            returnString += " " + modulo + "/" + this.denominator;
        }
        return returnString;
    }
    return this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator;
}
```

and this is the snippet for calculating the results for each operator

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == this.computeButton){
        try {
            Fraction f1 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(Den1.getText()));
            Fraction f2 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText()), Integer.parseInt(Den2.getText()));
            Fraction res;
            if (!Mixed1.getText().isEmpty())
                f1.setWholeNumber(Integer.parseInt(Mixed1.getText()));
            if (!Mixed2.getText().isEmpty()){
                f2.setWholeNumber(Integer.parseInt(Mixed2.getText()));
            }

            switch (comboBox1.getSelectedIndex()){
                case 0: //addition
                    res =f1.add(f2);
                    break;
                case 1://subtraction
                    res = f1.sub(f2);
                    break;
                case 2://multiplication
                    res = f1.mul(f2);
                    break;
                case 3://division
                    res = f1.div(f2);
                    break;

                default: res = new Fraction(1,1);
            }
            Label.setText(res.toString());
```

Comment: it would be better to create a "public String getResult()" method  instead of doing this in toString()

Comment: What is `wholeNumber` in your Fraction class ? is it the multiplicator?

Comment: How should your output be simplified? example: if the result was `10/2`, should it be displayed at `10/2` or `5*2/2` or `5/1` or `5`?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against having your `wholeNumber` as part of your `Fraction` class.
Instead I would make it a `Fraction` itself (`wholeNumber/1`):

```
Fraction mixed1 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Mixed1.getText()), 1);
Fraction fraction1 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(Den1.getText()));

Fraction mixed2 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Mixed2.getText()), 1);
Fraction fraction2 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText()), Integer.parseInt(Den2.getText()));
```

Then you have only fractions, and you can multiply them

```
Fraction f1 = fraction1.mul(mixed1);
Fraction f2 = fraction2.mul(mixed2);
```

Then you can use your original switch/case code afterwards.

Regarding the display I would do it like this:

```
public String getResult() {
    String returnString = this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator;
    if (this.numerator >= this.denominator) {
        int modulo = this.numerator % this.denominator;
        if(modulo == 0) {
            int divider = this.numerator / this.denominator;
            returnString = String.valueOf(divider);
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Outputs

```
Fraction(10, 2) -> 5
Fraction(9, 3) -> 3
Fraction(8, 3) -> 8/3
Fraction(5, 2) -> 5/2
```

**Note1:**

As mentionned by  Stultuske in a comment, you should probably not be using `toString` as it is a method you inherit from `Object`

But you can still overwrite it this way:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.numerator  + "/" + this.denominator;
}
```

So for example if your `Fraction` is `8/2`

```
toString() returns `8/2` 
getResultAsString() returns `2 * 5/4`
```

**Note2:**

Do not start your variable names with an uppercase, ex: `mixed1`, not `Mixed1`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer you in two ways:

1. About the result: 2/2+3/2=5/2, and it's not 0.

On every method you created to get the result on the `switch` (`sum`,`sub`,`div` and `mul`), try to multiply the entire number and the numerator, such as:

`this.numerator=*wholeNumber`

2. About the way results are shown:
   As Stultuske said on comments, try to do a `get` method instead of `toString`

Comment: pretty sure 2 + 3 is 5, not 6.

Comment: oof, mb. Just typed this after an exam and I was preety numb.